# Facebook FB.Event.subscribe does not work

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, event-handling, facebook-like

I'd like to follow how many likes I get on my page, but something is wrong. I am using the Facebook javascript event handler but it doesnt work.

It should alerts me when I click on the like or on the dislike button but it does not do anything. Any idea where I am wrong? Thanks! And sorry for my english.

Here is my UPDATED code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<title>FBlike check</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=00000000000000000";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
</script>
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/XYZ" send="false" layout="button_count" width="200" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well.. I tried a lot of versions than this one is worked perfectly:

```
<script>  
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'MY_APP_ID', 
                status: false,
                cookie: false, 
                xfbml: true
            });

            //Additional
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
                        function (response) {
                            alert('LIKED: ' + response);
                        }
                 );
        };

        // Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));

    </script>
    <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/MY_FB_PAGE" send="false" layout="button_count" width="200" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

I hope it can help for others.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the iframe version of the like button - the javascript events are only fired from the XFBML version - this is explained on the [Like Button documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

**How do I know when a user clicks a Like button?**

*If you are using the XFBML version of the button, you can subscribe to the 'edge.create' event through FB.Event.subscribe.*

Comment: I tried that too, but still doesn't work :( if I use the XFBML like button  than when I click on it a "post ot facebook" popup appears. Thats why I used the iframe version at the first time.

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to happen, it's part of the XFBML like button - you need to decide if you want the callback or you don't want users entering messages when they share your link

Comment: I understand, and the callback is more important in this case, but it still does not work even with the XFBML button. I added the XML namespace to the html tag, I changed the SDK include, and I changed the like button, but nothing happens. 

The test is here: [link](http://blog.nt-design.hu/fblikecheck/)

Comment: You're pulling the JS SDK in there twice, why is that? You're pulling in the SDK and pre-initialising it, then also initialising manually, then reloading the SDK again - could that be the problem?

Comment: Oh.. It seems I am too tired...
Now I deleted the "window.fbAsyncInit = ......." part, but the alert window doesnt appear :/